# How to write export using const in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, middleware, middy

I am using the middy package from npm. I need someone to tell me how to write the following code using `module.exports`

```
export default handler => middy(handler)
  .use([
   httpBodyParser,
   httpEventNormalizer,
   httpErrorHandler
])
```

The function above is anonymous which takes a handler function and wraps the middleware around it. How to write this using module.exports? Please help me!!

Comment: "latest JavaScript" wouldn't use `module.exports` at all, it would use [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) as the code shippet shown does. Is the question really how to do this the old way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"latest JavaScript" wouldn't use `module.exports` at all, it would use [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) as the code shippet shown does. If the question is really how to do this the old CommonJS way, you'd do it by assigning to `module.exports` directly:

```
// Old CommonJS way
module.exports = (handler) => middy(handler)
    .use([
      httpBodyParser,
      httpEventNormalizer,
      httpErrorHandler
   ]);
```

But if possible, I'd use standard JavaScript modules ("**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules" aka "ESM" — i.e., `export` and `import`) instead.

Comment: Thank u so much for this! Actually I did try using import and export in my code but I kep receiving errors on my AWS Cloudwatch. So I had to switch to module,exports syntax. Also. thanks for the info on which is latest. I have edited my question as well :)